# MySQL : left part of a string split by a separator string?

Tags: mysql, string, split, separator

I need a MySQL function to get the left part of a string with variable length, before the separator.

For example, with separator string '==' :

```
abcdef==12345     should return abcdef
abcdefgh==12      should return abcdefgh
```

Also the same thing, but for the right part...

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_name, '==', 1) FROM table ; // for left

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_name, '==', -1) FROM table; // for right
```

Answer (score 7):

```
select substring_index('abcdef==12345','==',1)
```

for the right part use -1 instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into the substring function in SQL which is SUBSTR, but it is more for set positions in the string, not so much for variable lengths.

http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-substring.html